# Cannot implicitly convert type string to int

Tags: c#, parsing

```
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter some numbers");
        int sum = 0;
        for(;;)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine ();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (input))
            {
                break;
            }
            int inputParsed = int.Parse (input.ToString ());
            int sumParsed = int.Parse (sum.ToString ());
            sum = sum + input; // throws an error here

            Console.WriteLine (sum);
```

I want my programme to show the sum of all numbers entered by user, by even though I have parsed all the variables needed, it throws an "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" error. What's wrong?

Comment: `.ToString()` on a string instance (`input`) is useless.

Comment: `int.Parse (sum.ToString ());` is effectively a no-op, best represented with just `sum`

Comment: Also, why are you converting `sum` to string so you can parse it on the same line? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Really, sum is already an integer, so sumParsed is just superfluous and should be removed.

Comment: Use `inputParsed` variable instead of `input`, as this one is parsed. Also, consider using int.TryParse as this guy is not throwing an exception in case sth wrong with parsing will happen.

Answer (score 8):

```
sum = sum + input; //throws an error here
```

should be:

```
sum = sum + inputParsed ;
```

You are using the original input instead of the parsed value. And you don't need `sumParsed` because you just keep the total sum in `sum` and you do no need to cast the int to a string and then parse it back to an integer.

Comment: As long as you're at it, you should mention that `int.Parse (input.ToString ());` can be simply `int.Parse (input);`

Answer (score 4):

to check if the input of the user is right i would prefer

```
int userInput = 0;
if( int.TryParse( input, out userInput ) == false )
{
     break;
}
```

This is just an advise and not directly a solution to your problem.
There are enough answers =)

Answer (score 2):

```
int inputParsed = int.Parse (input.ToString ());
            //int sumParsed = int.Parse (sum.ToString ());//no need
            sum = sum + inputParsed ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this entirely (Your original error was because you were trying to add a `string` to an `int`, and not the parsed input as an `int`)

```
Console.WriteLine ("Please enter some numbers");
int sum = 0;

while (true)
{
    int parsedInput = 0;
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && int.TryParse(input, out parsedInput))
    {
        sum += parsedInput;
        Console.WriteLine (sum);
    }
    else
    break;
}
```

Comment: If I wasn't busy at the moment I could have got this one :) Oh well, better late than never.

Comment: +1...but move the declaration of `parsedInput` into the body of the `while` loop :)